# How to remove item from list without Ember-data?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to remove an item from a list that I fetched via `jQuery.getJSON`. `Ember-data` is not really an option as long as it's not stable yet.

```
App.Project = Ember.Object.extend({
    remove: function() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/api/v1/projects/'+this.get('id'),
            type: 'DELETE'
        });
    }
});

App.Project.reopenClass({
    findAll: function() {
        return jQuery.getJSON('/api/v1/projects').then(
            function(response) {
                var projects = Ember.A();

                if (response.projects !== undefined) {
                    response.projects.forEach(function (project) {
                        projects.pushObject(App.Project.create(project));
                    });
                }

                return projects;
            }
        );
    }
});

App.ProjectsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Project.findAll();
    },

    events: {
        deleteProject: function(project) {
            project.remove();
        }
    }
});
```

When I press the following button, it executes the DELETE API call, but of course it doesn't remove the item from the array. How can I also remove that item from the array?

```
<button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" {{action 'deleteProject' this}}><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a full blown "ember-data free" example of find / add / remove

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    username: ''
});

App.Person.reopenClass({
    people: [],
    add: function(hash) {
        var person = App.Person.create(hash);
        this.people.pushObject(person);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/people/",
            data: hash,
            error: function() {
                alert("create failed");
            },
            success: function(response) {
                person.set('id', response.id);
            }
        });
    },
    remove: function(person) {
        this.people.removeObject(person);
        $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: "/people/" + person.id + "/",
            error: function() {
                alert("delete failed");
            }
        });
    },
    find: function() {
        var self = this;
        $.getJSON('/people/', function(response) {
            response.forEach(function(hash) {
                var person = App.Person.create(hash);
                Ember.run(self.people, self.people.pushObject, person);
            });
        }, this);
        return this.people;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `removeObject`.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableEnumerable.html

You'll need to get a reference to the content of your projects controller content and then pass the single project to the removeObject method.

```
projects.removeObject(project);
```

Comment: That indeed looks like what I need, but how can I get the set of projects? I tried `this.get('model').removeObject(project)` but the model doesn't have that method. Also `this.get('content')` is *undefined*.

Comment: It seems that I need an Ember.Set, but when I convert the findAll method to use an Ember.Set, I get a `Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver'` exception.

Comment: That link is now dead